# How to set IF statement on GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, group-by

Hi I have query that confusing, this is the query

```
SELECT meta_value, meta_count, post_id
FROM wp_post_meta
GROUP BY IF(ISNULL(target_key), '', target_key) 
ORDER BY `meta_count` DESC 
LIMIT 30
```

Some of target key is null but some is value exist, how can I make result if target_key is value exist make it GROUP BY but if empty GROUP BY disabled

Anyone can help me?

Comment: For me, your question is a lot more confusing than your query...

Answer (score 2):

When the `target_key` is `null` you can use a value that is unique for each record to group by, so that those records will each end up in their own groups. For example if the `post_id` is a key for the table, you can group by that. You might need to add a prefix for the different values if the key could have the same value as the `target_key` field:

```
GROUP BY IF(ISNULL(target_key), 'x' + post_id, 'y' + target_key)
```

Note that your query is grouping on `target_key`, but you are selecting other fields without using aggregates (min, max, count, et.c.), so the result will be the values from any arbitrary record within each group. If those values are not the same for all records in each group, the result in unpredictable.

Comment: I have try this 



SELECT `meta_value`,`meta_count`,`post_id` FROM `wp_stt2_meta` GROUP BY IF(ISNULL(target_key), meta_value, 'y' + target_key) ORDER BY `meta_count` DESC LIMIT 30



The result only two, the field that target_key empty become one group, how to make it if target_key empty become GROUP BY meta_value?

Comment: @MasonAnthony: By empty, do you mean an empty string value rather than `null`? In that case you would need something like `group by case target_key when '' then meta_value else target_key end`.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT meta_value,meta_count,post_id
FROM wp_post_meta
WHERE target_key IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY target_key

UNION ALL

SELECT meta_value,meta_count,post_id
FROM wp_post_meta
WHERE target_key IS NULL

ORDER BY meta_count DESC
LIMIT 30
```

Just a rough idea. Not tested, though, and I'm not sure if that's what you want.

Comment: Removed unnecessary enclosing.

Comment: @ypercube First I hadn't enclosed it but then I figured out the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` might only affect the second `SELECT` part. Or am I wrong?

Comment: No, the `ORDER BY / LIMIT` clause affects the whole query.

Comment: @MasonAnthony You might wanna click on the checkmark in my response to mark your issue as solved, then ;)